# How to set the default JDBC URL value in H2 console using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I have enable the H2 console in spring boot. However, when I open the console connection page the default url is the one staved in the H2 console history.  How can i configure the project to populate the URL to be the same as **spring.datasource.url** on project start? Currently I set the url in the console manually but I would like to have it setup automatically by the project itself.

yaml:

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /admin/h2


  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:foobar
```

**update:**
I know that the last connection settings are saved to ~/.h2.server.properties but what I need is to set the properties from the starting application potentially, potentially switching between several of them

Comment: Are you looking for this ? -  spring.h2.console.enabled=false # Whether to enable the console.
spring.h2.console.path=/admin/h2 # Path at which the console is available. Take a look at this - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: from the h2.console properties I can see there only:  spring.h2.console.enabled|path|settings.trace|settings|web-allow-others. Neither of them seems to set the default URL

Comment: Have you tried this ? - spring.h2.console.path=/admin/h2

Comment: yes. it is  in the body of the question. However, this path sets the url of the console itself not the URL of the JDBC connection

Comment: Doesn't it become the one in history after you set it manually the first time?

Comment: The problem is the first time or when you have alternate between the projects with slightly different db name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no hook provided to fill in settings.

The good news is that we can change that with a bit of code.

**Current state**

The Login screen is created in `WebApp.index()`

```java
String[] settingNames = server.getSettingNames();
String setting = attributes.getProperty("setting");
if (setting == null && settingNames.length > 0) {
    setting = settingNames[0];
}
String combobox = getComboBox(settingNames, setting);
session.put("settingsList", combobox);
ConnectionInfo info = server.getSetting(setting);
if (info == null) {
    info = new ConnectionInfo();
}
session.put("setting", PageParser.escapeHtmlData(setting));
session.put("name", PageParser.escapeHtmlData(setting));
session.put("driver", PageParser.escapeHtmlData(info.driver));
session.put("url", PageParser.escapeHtmlData(info.url));
session.put("user", PageParser.escapeHtmlData(info.user));
return "index.jsp";
```

We want to tap into `server.getSettingNames()`, and precisely into `server.getSettings()` used underneath.

```java
synchronized ArrayList<ConnectionInfo> getSettings() {
    ArrayList<ConnectionInfo> settings = new ArrayList<>();
    if (connInfoMap.size() == 0) {
        Properties prop = loadProperties();
        if (prop.size() == 0) {
            for (String gen : GENERIC) {
                ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo(gen);
                settings.add(info);
                updateSetting(info);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0;; i++) {
                String data = prop.getProperty(Integer.toString(i));
                if (data == null) {
                    break;
                }
                ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo(data);
                settings.add(info);
                updateSetting(info);
            }
        }
    } else {
        settings.addAll(connInfoMap.values());
    }
    Collections.sort(settings);
    return settings;
}
```

**The plan**

- disable `ServletRegistrationBean<WebServlet>` created by `H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration`
- replace it with our config class with a subclass of `WebServlet`
- our `CustomH2WebServlet` will override `init` and register `CustomH2WebServer` (subclass of `WebServer`)
- in `CustomH2WebServer` we override `getSettings()` and we are done

**The Code**

```java
@EnableConfigurationProperties({H2ConsoleProperties.class, DataSourceProperties.class})
@Configuration
public class H2Config {

    private final H2ConsoleProperties h2ConsoleProperties;

    private final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    public H2Config(H2ConsoleProperties h2ConsoleProperties, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        this.h2ConsoleProperties = h2ConsoleProperties;
        this.dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<WebServlet> h2Console() {
        String path = this.h2ConsoleProperties.getPath();
        String urlMapping = path + (path.endsWith("/") ? "*" : "/*");
        ServletRegistrationBean<WebServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
                new CustomH2WebServlet(this.dataSourceProperties.getUrl()), urlMapping);
        H2ConsoleProperties.Settings settings = this.h2ConsoleProperties.getSettings();
        if (settings.isTrace()) {
            registration.addInitParameter("trace", "");
        }
        if (settings.isWebAllowOthers()) {
            registration.addInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "");
        }
        return registration;
    }
}
```

```java
package org.h2.server.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class CustomH2WebServlet extends WebServlet {

    private final String dbUrl;

    public CustomH2WebServlet(String dbUrl) {
        this.dbUrl = dbUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
        Enumeration<?> en = config.getInitParameterNames();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = en.nextElement().toString();
            String value = config.getInitParameter(name);
            if (!name.startsWith("-")) {
                name = "-" + name;
            }
            list.add(name);
            if (value.length() > 0) {
                list.add(value);
            }
        }
        String[] args = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        WebServer server = new CustomH2WebServer(dbUrl);
        server.setAllowChunked(false);
        server.init(args);
        setServerWithReflection(this, server);
    }

    private static void setServerWithReflection(final WebServlet classInstance, final WebServer newValue) {
        try {
            final Field field = WebServlet.class.getDeclaredField("server");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(classInstance, newValue);
        }
        catch (SecurityException|NoSuchFieldException|IllegalArgumentException|IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package org.h2.server.web;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class CustomH2WebServer extends WebServer {

    private final String connectionInfo;

    CustomH2WebServer(String dbUrl) {

        this.connectionInfo = "Test H2 (Embedded)|org.h2.Driver|" +dbUrl+"|sa";
    }

    synchronized ArrayList<ConnectionInfo> getSettings() {
        ArrayList<ConnectionInfo> settings = new ArrayList<>();
        ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo(connectionInfo);
        settings.add(info);
        updateSetting(info);
        Collections.sort(settings);
        return settings;
    }
}
```

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:foobar
```

Everything went smoolthly, except of one private field that needed to be set via reflection.

The code provided works with H2 1.4.199

Answer (score 4):

Inspired in @Lesiak's answer, using a simple and easier configuration class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;
import org.h2.server.web.ConnectionInfo;
import org.h2.server.web.WebServer;

import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@CommonsLog
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.h2.console", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class H2ConsoleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean<WebServlet> h2ConsoleRegistrationBean(final ServletRegistrationBean<WebServlet> h2Console, final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        h2Console.setServlet(new WebServlet() {
            @Override
            public void init() {
                super.init();
                updateWebServlet(this, dataSourceProperties);
            }
        });
        return h2Console;
    }

    public static void updateWebServlet(final WebServlet webServlet, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        try {
            updateWebServer(getWebServer(webServlet), dataSourceProperties);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | NullPointerException ex) {
            log.error("Unable to set a custom ConnectionInfo for H2 console", ex);
        }
    }

    public static WebServer getWebServer(final WebServlet webServlet) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        final Field field = WebServlet.class.getDeclaredField("server");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (WebServer) field.get(webServlet);
    }

    public static void updateWebServer(final WebServer webServer, final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        final ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(String.format("Generic Spring Datasource|%s|%s|%s", dataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(), dataSourceProperties.determineUrl(), dataSourceProperties.determineUsername()));
        final Method method = WebServer.class.getDeclaredMethod("updateSetting", ConnectionInfo.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(webServer, connectionInfo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just to make it clear: This sets the H2 console's JDBC URL to the same value as the `spring.datasource.url` value defined in application.properties